# Mac webcam - get the device

Tags: mac, terminal, video, unix

How do I access my default video camera on my mac? I know on Linux it is /dev/video0 but my Mac does not have that. I'm trying to capture my webcam into ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0
```

But it won't work because /dev/video0 doesn't exist.

Comment: Technically, the API for calling the camera exists in the Aqua layer, so you would have to negotiate that entire framework. It's a huge security risk so I doubt it will ever be made as easy as `/dev/videoX`, but I've been way wrong before :-)

Comment: Also - why not expand the question to say what you want to do - there might be many built in tools that do what you want to do even if your familiar tool is missing. You might be looking for a knife and some matches when the mac has delivery service and you could straight out just order a pizza.

Comment: Some great programs that help in capture video have popped up over there [command line control of the built in camera](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18160/command-line-control-of-the-built-in-camera)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it appears that ffmpeg can't record using the iSight, as reported in [a ffmpeg-users thread](http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/iSight-capture-td955162.html).

Really a shame that Apple doesn't expose this functionality!

Answer (score 2):

Macs use the AVFoundation framework to expose the camera programatically.

You'll want to start with the [StopNGo sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/StopNGoOSX/History/History.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011121-RevisionHistory-DontLinkElementID_1) if you've got a copy of Xcode. (and just browsing the source may help figure if you care to go down that path without needing Xcode to make a decision)

It would be a big security risk to expose that API to the terminal on every mac by default, but someone may have writen a bridge you could use.

You might need to ask that specifically on the programming sites. Your query looking for an equivalent to attaching a pre-existing device is advanced consumer and on-topic here. Getting into API usage is generally off topic even when the simple "consumer" answer is "no - the equivalent video device isn't available on Mac OS X"