# How  I take photo using the MBP's webcam from   command line?

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I take a steathy picture with my iSight camera from the command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18160/how-do-i-take-a-steathy-picture-with-my-isight-camera-from-the-command-line)

Is there a command line method for taking ?