# How to take photo using Terminal?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, mac, camera

Is it possible to take a photo or record a short video with the MacBook's webcam using Terminal?

```
sh-3.2# system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType 
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: macOS 10.13.4 (17E199)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 17.5.0
      Boot Volume: lily
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Computer Name: lily’s MacBook Air
      User Name: System Administrator (root)
      Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
      System Integrity Protection: Enabled
```

Comment: If you are not aware `apropos` is your friend. `apropos screen capture` brought up `screencapture(1)`. `man screencapture` will explain how to use the utility.

Comment: @fd0 thank you, i wasnt aware of `apropos`. it seems screencapture is used for capturing screenshots of the desktop. i didnt find any interesting commands using `$ apropos camera` or `$ apropos webcam`. any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Use [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/).

(This has become one of my favorite command line utilities for video/audio conversion and streaming)

According to the [FFMPEG Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam#AVFoundation), you can use Apple's AVFoundation to capture directly from the FaceTime Camera or any other USB web cam that's attached.  Keep in mind, the wiki was written when the FaceTime camera was still called the iSight so some of the features/keywords are no longer valid

#### Get the device ID

```
$ ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""

[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fda1bc152c0] AVFoundation video devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fda1bc152c0] [0] FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fda1bc152c0] [1] Capture screen 0
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fda1bc152c0] AVFoundation audio devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fda1bc152c0] [0] USB Audio CODEC
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fda1bc152c0] [1] Built-in Microphone
```

The device we're looking for is "0"

#### Capture the photo

```
$ ffmpeg -ss 0.5 -f avfoundation -i "0" -t 1 capture.jpg
```

What this does is take a 1 second video stream, takes the single fram starting at .5 seconds and saves it as a JPEG called `capture.jpg`

Answer (score 4):

Allan's reply above worked but with a few modifications. I'm using a MacBook Pro running Big Sur.

I had to add the frame rate & also use the command -frames:v 1 to export a single image.

```
ffmpeg -ss 0.5 -f avfoundation -r 30.000030 -i "0" -t 1 capture.jpg -frames:v 1
```

Comment: `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -f avfoundation -r 30.000030 -i "1" -t 1 -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 capture.jpg` is what did it for me, thanks for the help!

Comment: Can we get a 2022 update?

Comment: It's 2023 and the above comment featuring 00:00:00 works best for me (make sure you're capturing the correct device number). The solution this comment is attached to also works, but generates a warning. And finally, the accepted solution does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Third-party utilities like [`imagesnap`](https://github.com/rharder/imagesnap) and [`iSightCapture`](https://github.com/RandyMcMillan/iSightCapture) would work, but I suspect you are looking for something built in?

This has been asked before in diffrent wording: [How do I take a steathy picture with my iSight camera from the command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18160/how-do-i-take-a-steathy-picture-with-my-isight-camera-from-the-command-line)

Comment: `imagesnap` works well with zero-config.