# Add access to the macbook camera for the terminal application

Tags: terminal, camera

I am trying to run a `OpenCV` tutorial that uses the `cv.VideoCapture(0)`. This does require permission from terminal to access the camera. Here is a blog description showing that *they* see the `terminal` app included in the Applications list:

[image]

But for me the `Terminal` is not provided as an optional App:

[image]

That is actually not at all surprising. But then how to add `Terminal`?  The apple docs only show this:  https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/control-access-to-your-camera-on-mac-mchlf6d108da/mac :

[image]

No mention of how to add *other* apps is included.  So how to add `Terminal`?  (Actually I would also be interested in adding for `iTerm2` ..)

Comment: Try to `tccutil reset Camera` from your system terminal (not iTerm2). And then run iTerm2 again, it should ask for the permission to access your Camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force your terminal to request access to your Camera.

### I used the following commands (*these are meant to click a picture from your MacBook's camera)*:

`ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""`

List the devices attached to your computer. Get the device ID of your camera

---

`ffmpeg -ss 0.5 -f avfoundation -i "0" -t 1 capture.jpg`

Capture the photo.

---

Although this did not click a picture *(returned an error)*, but it did force the terminal to ask permission to access the Camera.

P.S: You need to have the `ffmpeg` package installed. You can do `brew install ffmpeg`

I got these commands from [this stackoverflow answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/326389/180133)

**Update by Question Asker**  This does work and here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: This worked: nice idea. I have updated your answer with the screenshot