# How to get dev of webcam (not iSight)

Tags: webcam

I am trying to stream with ffmpeg a webcam. I am on a MBP mid-'09 running Lion. I know that you can not have direct access to the iSight (Although open-cv seems to be able to...) so I have an external camera.

I know that the camera works, since I use it on Linux and that OS X recognizes it since it pops up in Photo Booth.

I am looking for something to the effect of /dev/video0 but can't seem to find any.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit: That question is similar, however they are asking specifically for the iSight camera. If there is an answer to that one, I would not need to use my USB camera. So I am keeping an eye on that question as well.

Edit: In system information, it reports Venus USB 2.0 Camera.

Comment: Is this the equivalent of your question? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16908/mac-webcam-get-the-device

Comment: If not, please add the exact camera model and if you have found any camera drivers that might be able to be loaded. Anything you can provide us might help find you a solution.

Comment: It *is* possible to access iSight video output, see http://www.flownet.com/ron/code/movie-capture.m