# Find the path to my USB webcam on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, usb, webcam

I am trying to live stream my webcam (with ffmpeg) on a web server using Web sockets. However, I cannot manage to find the path (similar to /dev/video* un Linux).

I wanted first to use iSight, but Apple makes it really complex to access it (using avfoundation, qkit).

How can I identify/access my Webcam device please ?

**Note :** I have found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51112/how-to-get-dev-of-webcam-not-isight) post, but sadly unanswered.

Thanks

Comment: does your Mac actually recognizes the external device connect to USB ?

Comment: Yes I am able to use the usb webcam when opening Photo booth or Skype

Answer (score 1):

You should try the VLC player.

It has multitude of options for setting of the Capture and Streaming.

[image: capture]

I am not showing your set up since I do not have external webcam, but it should show in the drop down menu for you.