# Check Camera Path through command line

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, camera, webcam

is that a command to type in terminal that lists all the webcams connected to my computer? Maybe using ffmpeg package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ioreg` and `system_profiler` Will enumerate connected USB and other devices should you have a FireWire or other bus for a camera.

Sadly, ffmpeg won't see the path to these devices as described here:

- [Mac webcam - get the device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16908/mac-webcam-get-the-device)

At least you'll have a starting point with the two commands to detect a connedtd device.